# Replacing text with code

Tags: php

I need to replace text in file with code.
I've tried to use this method, but it didn't work for me.

```
ob_start();
include "core/menus.php";
$topmenu = ob_get_contents();
str_replace("$%TOPMENU%$", $topmenu, $template_path.'/index.tpl');
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: The `$template_path.'/index.tpl` is a file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch the HTML of core/menus.php, do that first:

```
ob_start();
include "core/menus.php";
$top_menu = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Then do the replacing. However, you'll need to fetch the contents of the template file before you can replace anything:

```
$template = file_get_contents($template_path.'/index.tpl');
$output = str_replace("$%TOPMENU%$", $topmenu, $template);
echo $output;
```

(I typed this on my phone, so please excuse any syntax mistakes. ;) )

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. If I use echo on end, it will display code to main file and this code doesn't replaced {TOPMENU} tag.

Comment: Maybe you know another method?

Comment: The method is correct, that I know for sure. The output may not be what you expected, but that may be caused by a lack of information on your part; you just gave a completely different string to replace: `{TOPMENU}`. Replace `$%TOPMENU%$` with that and try again.

Comment: Thank you. If you want I can show what did I get at end)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you have to change parameters order :D

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

And you aint used result of str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a result to (F) str_replace(...)

```
$newMenuIndex=str_replace("$%TOPMENU%$", $topmenu, $template_path.'/index.tpl');
```